# how to force sharepoint server 2013 to search part of a word

Tags: 2013, development, search, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

I am working on SharePoint server 2013. and currently if i want to search for the pages that contain words such as

> "email configuration"

then i need to type the whole 2 words.

But if i type something such as

> "email conf"

then i will NOT get any pages that have the words "email configuration" , so is there a way to modify this behavior ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually using quotes in the query? Have you tried searching for email conf* (without quotes)?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott but i can not force the users to enter * when searching , i need SharePoint to search for partial words by defualt ...

Comment: None that I am aware of that will work in the case you describe. I have added instructions in the search center as "Search Tips".